# Java how to verify hebrew text from the letter

Tags: java, regex, matching, hebrew

I need to verify hebrew text from the letter
the letter's body like:

> שלום,
>
> תואם ייעוץ וידאו עם המטופל John Salivan.  מועד הייעוץ נקבע לתאריך
>   23/02/2019 בשעה 20:45.
>
> לביצוע הייעוץ יש להכנס

but my regex doesn't match text

```
    public static void findBadLines(String fileName) {

    Pattern regexp =  Pattern.compile(".*שלום,.*תואם ייעוץ וידאו עם המטופל John Salivan. .*מועד הייעוץ נקבע לתאריך .* בשעה.*..*לביצוע הייעוץ יש להכנס .*");
    Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher("");

    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    //another way of getting all the lines:
    //Files.readAllLines(path, ENCODING);
    try (
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, ENCODING);
            LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
    ){
        String line = null;
        while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
            matcher.reset(line); //reset the input
            if (!matcher.find()) {
                String msg = "Line " + lineReader.getLineNumber() + " is bad: " + line;
                throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
```

}

Comment: maybe you are missing new line character

Comment: Try adding the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag, `Pattern.compile(".*שלום,.*תואם ייעוץ וידאו עם המטופל John Salivan. .*מועד הייעוץ נקבע לתאריך .* בשעה.*..*לביצוע הייעוץ יש להכנס .*", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: Thanks, it helped)

Answer (score 0):

Do I get that right, you wan't to check if there is any hebrew text in a given input?

If so use that regex `.*[\u0590-\u05ff]+.*`

`[\u0590-\u05ff]+` matches one or more hebrew characters, the `.*` before and after you need to match the rest of your input.

Respectively

```java
   Pattern regexp =  Pattern.compile(".*[\u0590-\u05ff]+.*");
        //...
        matcher.reset(line); //reset the input
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            String msg = "Line " + lineReader.getLineNumber() + " is bad: " + line;
            throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
        }
```

Comment: No, I need exactly verify all text- that body from the message contains correct text